# Select building facades that face the street

Tags: spatial-join, topology, fme-transformer

I have a set of buildings (building footprints) and a street network. The buildings have attribute
`Use`. I need to transfer the value of attribute `Use` as well as the length of the building façade that is adjacent to the street segment. See green lines drawn in the image below.

[image]

**What I have tried... ( I am using FME)**

I created centroid of the building and drew a straight line from the building centroid to the nearest line segment. Further I converted building polygon to line using `GeometryCoercer` transformer and subsequently chopped line using `Chopper` transformer to of or each side of the polygon. However, there are two problems:

1. the corner buildings only connect to one of the streets.
2. Using Geometry Coercer and Chopper breaks building edges into small lines (see the blue line in the image below )

[image]